# Retrieve users from Active Directory using ms-Ds-Consistency Guid

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldap-query

I have ms-ds-consistency guid to have the same value as objectGuid. But while trying to retrieve users using ms-ds-consistency guid, the AD object is not returned. Below is the query-

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)((ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid=\e7\13\f9\2a\73\9d\89\4e\a3\5b\4d\20\c7\35\94\a2)))
```

Is there a way to retrieve AD objects using ms-ds-consistency guid? Can someone please help me?

Comment: How are you querying for this? (Command-line JNDI or ???). Also no need for ObbjectClass or SamaccountName as the Guid MUST be unique. Try query for just objectGuid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value you are looking for is actually correct (you can verify in AD Users and Computers using the Attributes tab), then it *should* return results, but only if you are searching only the one domain.

The [`mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ms-ds-consistencyguid) attribute is not replicated to the Global Catalog. So if you are connected to the GC, you won't get results. You connect to the GC by using port 3269 or "Entire Directory" in ADUC.

However, this search will be very slow because `mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid` is not indexed. It has to look at every account in your domain to find a match. The more your other conditions filter down the results, the faster the query will perform. You could use `(objectClass=user)` to limit it to only user accounts, since `(objectCategory=person)` actually includes Contact and Computer objects too.

If you do use `(objectClass=user)`, then `(sAMAccountName=*)` condition wouldn't do anything for you, since it's a required attribute for users anyway.